# MP4 video working on desktop, not on mobile devices

Tags: ios, wordpress, video, mp4, h.264

I embedded a video in the following URL: https://www.speurtochten.nl/over-ons/
I made it with Premiere Pro CC, exported it as H.264.

The code I use in WordPress: `[video src="https://speurtochten.nl/sbsfilm.mp4"][/video]`

I tried uploading several dummy videos instead (http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4), and they worked perfectly fine on the desktop AND on a mobile phone.

On my iPhone, I get "Error loading this resource".

Comment: Did http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4 work on your iphone?

Comment: @Harry Yes it worked on my iphone

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @Clive maybe next time you can put a useful comment

Comment: Maybe next time you can ask a useful question.

Comment: As we also answer any ffmpeg question i guess that one is fine too... In case too many downvotes i suggest posting on superuser.com

Comment: @Harry there’s nothing about programming in the question or any potential answer - it’s gonna be closed

Comment: @Clive then how would you explain this problem?

Comment: I wouldn’t, I’d just look at the code and solve it. For the vast majority of cases on this site, if there’s no code element, it’s in the wrong place. Don’t take my word for it, leave it here and see what happens to it.

Comment: True, @user2034879 Clive is harsh but not totally wrong. Your question cannot really be answerred in the sense of stackoverflow answers. The only thing i see is that the video that does not work is interlaced, export a progressive one from premiere and try again. Please delete your question here and post on superuser including all details about your iphone

Comment: @Clive There is no other code, except the video tag of WordPress. When I change the .mp4 file with for example one on the url I posted, then all of a sudden it works

Comment: @Harry Not wrong at all, actually :) don’t confuse people getting straight to the point with harshness. Were volunteers, remember, we have to guard our time jealously

Comment: So we’re in agreement that this has nothing to do with programming. Which of course is bad, because you posted it to a site for questions about programming. Please do the decent thing. Delete it, and find somewhere appropriate to ask it.

Comment: Look, there’s an entire Stack Exchange site dedicated to Wordpress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ which is happy to receive questions that are about Wordpress but aren’t about programming. That’s where this should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accepting and agreeing with the comments that this is a borderline coding question/answer, I'll try to provide an answer but within a coding context(ish...), or at least referring to the tools a developer might typically use to debug this type of problem.

Debugging this type of issue is tricky but it can help to use the debugger tools - you can attach a mobile phone to a Mac/PC and use the Chrome or Safari developer tools to look at the console and the network traffic to try to see the reason for an error like this. Example link (correct at the time of writing, but in case link breaks/moves the summary is: attach device, enable USB debugging; click on inspect button in devices tab to open tools to inspect the device) for instructions for Chrome developer tools here:

- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Doing this will in your case show that the site is loading fine (expect for an unrelated HTTPS css issue).

You can also view the page source and find the video URL and then open a tab, from the tools window, to play the video directly on the mobile browser.

In your case the video does not play.

Looking at the page source also allows you see that the video player being used if mediaelement.js - most web video playback uses some form of HTML5/javascript player in addition to the video tag.

This player is opensource (https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement) so the code can be checked, on GitHub, which provides the ability to search an entire version of the repository for a text string quite easily. Checking for the error string or even parts of it quickly shows that this error is not generated by the player (or not the current version anyway - if you wanted to be meticulous you could make sure and check whatever version is used in your webpage).

This suggests that the issue is with the underlying browser or device video support itself.

Downloading the video and looking at its properties using ffprobe (https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) shows output including the following:

```js
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sbsfilm.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-11-23T19:23:40.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:06.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10311 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9989 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
```

The key information here is the 'High' part which means it is a H.264 High profile video. H.264 has different profiles and many different potential settings and options, so we can't just say that a device will play H.264, instead we need to look at more detail.

Looking at the Android support media types (again at the time of writing...) shows that High Profile is not in the listed supported types (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html):

[image]

This is quite likely to be your problem - if you re-encode the video to H.264 Main or Baseline profile and try again the video should work on Mobile devices (baseline is the most supported but does not offer as good compression as Mainline so you may want to experiment to find the best match for your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Recently had the issue. The video file was interlaced. Once I rendered it progressive it was fine.